Token copy of Mirrorhall Mimic cloning a TDFC
Mirrorhall Mimic is somewhat unique in that it's a clone which is also able to transform. Let's say I have it enter as another transforming double-faced card such as Ravager of the Fells. From other similar questions asked I've come to understand that even if Mirrorhall Mimic transforms, it will remain a Ravager of the Fells since the copy effect is a continuous effect. While, on the other hand, if I copied the original Ravager of the Fells with a Cackling Counterpart then the token would be able to transform between Ravager of the Fells and the front face Huntmaster of the Fells since it has the copiable values as intrinsic characteristics.
What I haven't been able to find an answer to is what happens if I use Cackling Counterpart to copy my Mirrorhall Mimic clone of Ravager of the Fells. Will the token then be a transforming token with Ravager of the Fells as both it's faces or will this token also be able to transform between Ravager of the Fells and Huntmaster of the Fells?

The token is a double-faced token with a copy of Ravager of the Fells that is also a Spirit on both sides.
The rules that apply here are 707.8 and 707.8a:

707.8. When copying a melded permanent or other double-faced permanent, use the copiable values of the face that's currently up to determine the characteristics of the copy. See rule 712, "Double-Faced Cards."

707.8a. If an effect creates a token that is a copy of a transforming permanent or a transforming double-faced card not on the battlefield, the resulting token is a transforming token that has both a front face and a back face. The characteristics of each face are determined by the copiable values of the same face of the permanent it is a copy of, as modified by any other copy effects that apply to that permanent. If the token is a copy of a transforming permanent with its back face up, the token enters the battlefield with its back face up. This rule does not apply to tokens that are created with their own set of characteristics and enter the battlefield as a copy of a transforming permanent due to a replacement effect.


First, rule 707.8 describes how Mirrorhall Mimic's own effect works. The copy effect it creates makes it a copy of just the Ravager of the Fells face, except that it is also a Spirit.
Then rule 707.8a describes how creating the token will work. Mirrorhall Mimic is a transforming permanent, so the token will be a transforming token. Since the characteristics of each face are modified by Mirrorhall Mimic's copy effect, each face will be a copy of the Ravager of the Fells, except that it is also a Spirit. Since Mirrorhall Mimic may have transformed since it entered, either side could be up when the token is created, so the token will enter with the corresponding side up.
